# Mapbox + Swift: changing Layer Image

Tags: swift, mapbox

I'm trying to dynamically change an image in added layer in Mapbox. My (appropriate part of) code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
    let weatherSource = MGLImageSource(identifier: "weatherSource", coordinateQuad: radarCoordinates, image: radarImages[radarImages.count-1])   
    let weatherLayer = MGLRasterStyleLayer(identifier: "weatherLayer", source: weatherSource)    
    radarTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(changeRadar), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)    
    style.addSource(weatherSource)
    style.addLayer(weatherLayer)
    self.weatherLayer = weatherLayer 
}
```

And the update function:

```
@objc func changeRadar() {
    snap = (snap != radarImages.count-1 ? snap+1 : 0)
    weatherSource.image = (radarImages[snap] == nil ? radarImages[snap-1] : radarImages[snap])
}
```

Nothing happens, when I start the app, but it should change the images contained in the array radarImages (contains radar pictures).

Any idea what can I do better to let it work?

Comment: Hi. Have you confirmed that changeRadar is actually called?

Comment: I think it is called from the timer (radarTimer). If I add a print() to the changeRadar function, it's looping texts to the console.